# ContentNotRenderedError while using django middleware

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I used process_request and process_response functions in django middleware in order to log the requests before hitting the viewset.  But, I get Internal Server Error.  I don't understand what's wrong with my code.

```
class MyMiddleware(): 
    def process_request( self, request ): 
        print "xxxxx"
        return Response( status=status.HTTP_200_OK ) 
    def process_response( self, request, response ): 
        print "xxxxx" 
        return Response( status=status.HTTP_200_OK )
```

What am I missing?
The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 118, in __iter__
    raise ContentNotRenderedError('The response content must be '
ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.

----------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 124, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 92, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 33, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 118, in __iter__
    raise ContentNotRenderedError('The response content must be '
ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.

----------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 124, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 92, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 33, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: What server are you using? What Python version?

Comment: @linuxfreak What's the error message? Please add it in the question.

Comment: I have added the error in the question

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `return Response()` in your middleware methods.

If you return a response in the [`process_request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process-request) method, then Django will not call the view. You probably don't want to return anything here.

You should return a response from the [`process_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process-response) method. You probably want to return the original response from the view (`response`) here. If you return a different response (e.g. `Response(...)`), then Django will return this to the user instead of the response from the view.

```
class MyMiddleware(): 
    def process_request(self, request): 
        print "xxxxx"

    def process_response(self, request, response): 
        print "xxxxx"
        return response
```

See the Django docs for more information about what you should return from each middleware method.

Comment: As per django documents,we can return Response object from both process_request and process_response.  Anyway, I tried not returning from process_request like you said and hit the following error:

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 33, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 96, in wrapper
    et, ev, tb = sys.exc_info()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exc_info'

Comment: Yes, the Django docs say you *can* return a `Response` object from `process_request`, but that means that Django will return that response to the user, instead of processing the view. There's no point in having any views if you middleware always returns a response from your middleware instead. Similarly, if you always return `Response(...)` from `process_response`, then Django will return that response instead of the response from the view.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue.  It's because the response object returned by process_response doesn't have actual response.  I modified it to following and it worked.

```
class MyMiddleware(): 
    def process_request( self, request ): 
        print "xxxxx"
        return None
    def process_response( self, request, response ): 
        print "xxxxx" 
        return response
```